# How get track name from pls file(online stream)? (jPlayer, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio-streaming, jplayer, internet-radio

Are there any solutions to get the track's name from a pls file? (or a stream)

I use the jPlayer, but I can't find information, how can I get the tracks' name...
I would like to view the track's name, like the winamp or another music player programs.
Maybe I have to encoding the streaming? ( I don't have any idea for this problem...)

```
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"http://87.117.193.10:8000/;stream1"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3",
    //wmode: "window"
}).jPlayer("play");
```